# How can I show and scroll one line at a time in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I am trying to get the window for Microsoft Word 2010 to show a single line of text at one time. I'm able to do this by resizing the window to show a single line and pressing the down arrow one tap at a time. However, when I reach the bottom of a paragraph, the scroll skips past the bottom line. My document is set to add a line of blank space automatically between paragraphs, if that helps.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. It seems you are trying to solve a larger problem in a specific way (XY problem). You might get more helpful answers if you describe the larger problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I reviewed the link you shared, and I'm not sure how to describe a larger problem. Essentially, I want a minimalistic view of the copy in my Word document. I've found that viewing one line at a time helps me to focus on the copy in editing, so that's what I'd like to set up. However, when I tap down to scroll in this view, Word "jumps" past the last line before the end of a paragraph. I'm not sure how to keep Word from jumping past this line. Open to suggestions about rephrasing!

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a delimiter like an underscore and then use the find function and click next to get through each line

Comment: True, this will work, but it's pretty labor intensive to add an underscore at the beginning of every line. I'd also then have to remove the underscores.